# How to install a program from a .pkg file on ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, windows, emulation

I recently downloaded microsoft office visio and was planning on using wine to install it on my laptop running ubuntu 12.04. But I can't access the .exe file.

Comment: Please go to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72226/installing-pkg-with-terminal and view the discussions for more help

Answer (score 0):

.pkg file is the extension of mac apps, there is no wine like apps are available to run mac apps on ubuntu